# JQuery events mouseenter and mouseleave not fired for IE 10, workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Update: found possible cause, when I confirm it I will post it as an answer

I found something interesting about IE behaviour.

Opposed to the example I posted on jsfiddle, my original page shows an image in the background (sorry for omitting it, I considered it not relevant). Not as a css background property but as an img element that comes before the divs with the mouseenter/mouseleave event handlers. I do not use z-index property (and I already confirmed that use it changes nothing) I found that when this is the case (an img element followed by absolute positioned divs that should render on top of it) IE only fires mouseleave/mouseenter events on visible parts of the divs. In my case, I discovered this by adding (border-style: solid) and a (border-width) of considerable size to all the divs. IE fires mouseenter when mouse pointer enters the div's border and then fires mouseleave when mouse pointer is no more over the border pixels even if it is inside the div (probably because the div is transparent). If no borders (as my original code) no mouseenter events.

In jsfiddle this was not reproduced. But if I add the img element should be 100% reproducible.

Possible workaround (I will test it right now and update): div background pixels must not be transparent or mouseleave will be fired right after the pointer is no more over the border pixels, if no borders then no mouseenter/mouseleave will be fired. Use a png background image for the divs with all pixels 1% opaque should do the trick. Maybe the css opacity property (without any background image but with a solid background color) may work too.

More info:

- my doctype is <!DOCTYPE html>
- I need the background image to be an img element, is not practical
  in this case to use a css background property.

### Original question:

IE 10 console is not providing any useful information. I started to use console.log in different parts of the script and come to the conclusion that mouseenter and mouseleave aren't fired for IE 10, don't sure in other IE versions. Works OK in Chrome and Firefox, and probably Opera.

This code result in no output in the console (for IE). It should at least prints "IE TEST 2".

```
console.log("IE TEST 1"); // OK
$(".show_on_mouseenter").mouseenter(function (evt) {
    console.log("IE TEST 2"); // nothing is print
    showContent(this);
});

$(".hide_on_mouseleave").mouseleave(function (evt) {hideContent(this)});

console.log("IE TEST 3"); // OK
```

For now I will try to emulate mouseenter/mouseleave using mouseover. But It would be great If the code just works on IE as It is now.

I tried to replicate only the relevant part of the code in jsfiddle. This time It worked for IE 10 too. I'm doing nothing really before those lines of code, maybe are my styles that are causing the problem. I modified my css to make the content divs and control divs visible from the start and they position and size is as expected in IE 10. My original hideContent and showContent functions have more code that the one I showing at jsfiddle but they aren't the problem because in my IE 10 they aren't being called as the previous console.log() line is not executed.

Code at jsfiddle showing how the script should behave. You move the mouse over the div, and another div appears, then you move the mouse out of the first div, and the content is hidden again. You will see a lot of suspicious values like "left: 14.321px". That is because my original code calculates left, top, width and height and produces not truncated values, as every browser I have tested accepted those values, I simply let them as doubles. Also some of them are as percentages, but in jsfiddle I used px in all cases because I'm entering them manually.

http://jsfiddle.net/xhzCL/

For some reason this code works in IE 10. jquery version is the same I'm using. I cannot replicate the problem in jsfiddle.

More info: Console is clear except for my own console.log() lines. I'm downloading my page from an http server running in another machine connected to my router. I remember something about an IE security police causing troubles with scripts of pages loading from intranet. May be this the problem?

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave events are supported in IE. So could you provide more of relevant code (HTML) and a jsfiddle which replicates your issue?!

Comment: Done. I could not replicate the problem in jsfiddle. May this be caused by an IE security police?

Comment: Any error in console? You should remove all CSS, remove all irrelevant code and try to target what makes your code not working on your site. Obviously, issue is not from anything you have posted here, so no one should be able to help you more. In simple words, you have to debug it on your side

Comment: is `.show_on_mouseenter` already in the DOM when the event is created ? Otherwise you may have to use `$("body").on("mousenter",".show_on_mouseenter", function() { });`

Comment: Is already in the DOM. In my first version I loaded all the control divs and content divs through AJAX but I realized that may result in a bad relation with search engines then I modified things to make sure all divs and their texts are already there when dowloaded from server (a php script handles this) and the content is there because I can see it in the page html. Also the event handler is assigned on window.onload = function () {[the code]} and jquery is loaded first by a previous <script> element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the console is clear except for the console.log() lines is because there is nothing wrong in the Javascript code. Nothing wrong with the css or html. The problem is how IE 10 (and probably other versions of the same browser) behaves.

It seems that IE understands that mouseenter must be fired when the mouse pointer enters a **visible** part of the element and mouseleave must be fired when mouse pointer leaves a **visible** part of the element. This is not the case if nothing is below the element (visually) but things change when there is something below the div and due to div having no content or background-color the other element's pixels can be seen through it. Adding the css properties **background-color: white** and **opacity: 0.0001** easily makes IE behave like all other browsers for this specific situation without the background-color becoming noticeable to the eye.

The following links must be visited using IE 10 (probably 9 and maybe 8) as other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari) will fire the events in any case.

- Demo reproducing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xhzCL/5/
- Demo solving the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xhzCL/6/
- Update: by using two inner divs is possible to have visible borders and still have consistent cross browser behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/xhzCL/9/

The difference are in these two css lines:

```
background-color: white;
opacity: 0.0001;
```

Or with jquery:

```
$(".show_on_mouseenter").css("background-color", "white").css("opacity", "0.0001");
```

Note that the proposed solution will hide also the borders of the div that should fire the mouse events. That's OK with OP needs, may not be OK for other situations. Try to remember where the div was in demo 1, then go there with the mouse pointer, the text will be visible while the pointer is over the full div body, no matters where exactly, while in demo 1 the text will be visible only when the pointer is over the border's pixels and will hide when the pointer is near the center of the div (opposed to the behaviour of all other browsers).

If OP had included the img element from the beginning others would run into the same problem and found a similar solution. Sorry for that, I was sure the img was not related to this and paste the full page code into jsfiddle was not practical.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this instead

```
$(".show_on_mouseenter").on("mouseenter", function (evt) {
console.log("IE TEST 2"); // nothing is print
showContent(this);
});
```

Comment: But I tried anyway. Same results as expected, the content divs do not show on IE. Also I tried "mouseenter.control_div" and off("mouseenter").on("mouseenter", [handler here]) with the same results. Chrome and Firefox Ok, IE doesn't like my code.